# How do I modify a page title based on react component using .NET Core react with redux project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, redux

I thought this would be simple, and the answer probably is and I'm just missing something, but I'm having trouble with updating a header/layout component based on what page I'm on.

Code wise, I have just installed the ASP.NET Core 2.0 [template that uses React with Redux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/react-with-redux?view=aspnetcore-2.0). I'm familiar with React, but TypeScript and Redux is new to me so it's hopefully a syntax/layout issue I'm having, as I can do this in a standalone React project. If you create a new project in Visual Studio following this template, you'll see the code that I'm trying to modify (New > Project > ASP.NET Core Web Application > React.js and Redux).

The TypeScript Layout file (`ClientApp/components/Layout.tsx`) is where I want to put essentially:

```
<h1>{ this.state.title }</h1>
```

...and further on from this use a Header tag to load a Header component that holds the title.

I want to then change the title based on whether I am on the Home, FetchData, or Counter page, which I imagine is just a basic string set on each component file.

If you can't open the project file for whatever reason, here is the layout I'm working with:

**Layout component (should set the title here)**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavMenu } from './NavMenu';

export interface HeaderState {
    title: string;
}

export class Layout extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    public render() {
        return <div className='container-fluid'>
            // !!!!---> Create a <Header /> component that includes the page title, set on a page by page basis
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-sm-3'>
                    <NavMenu />
                </div>
                <div className='col-sm-9'>
                    { this.props.children }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

I would potentially include more component code for those who can't use the Visual Studio project, but it's pretty bloated with a lot of code that doesn't apply here. I just thought someone could help without needing it, but happy to provide if necessary!

Any help or pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated! Apologies if this question and answer is somewhere. I have Googled and searched SO but no luck.